# Associating a uicontextmenu in Matlab with a Java Swing JTable

Tags: java, matlab, jtable, contextmenu, jscrollpane

The following test code is an attempt to link a Matlab context menu to a javax.swing.JTable.  The JTable shows up ok and the right-mouse click does enter the appropriate section of code (at the bottom).  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

```
function test
% Initialize
hMain = [];

% Set up figure window
initial_position = [100 300 925 475];
hMain.fMain = figure('NumberTitle','off',...
    'name','Test Table',...
    'Toolbar','no','menubar','no','DockControls','off',...
    'Position',initial_position,'visible','on',...
    'CloseRequestFcn',@CB_Project_Quit);

% Set up context menu
cmenu = uicontextmenu('Parent',hMain.fMain,...
    'Interruptible','off','Visible','on','Tag','ContextMenu');

% Define the context menu items
item1 = uimenu(cmenu, 'Label', 'Test1');
item2 = uimenu(cmenu, 'Label', 'Test2');
item3 = uimenu(cmenu, 'Label', 'Test3');

% Create JTable
hMain.Tabs.hTable=javax.swing.JTable(8,8);
hMain.Tabs.hPanel=jcontrol(hMain.fMain, 'javax.swing.JScrollPane',...
    'Units','pixels','Position', [12 12 900 450],...
    'UIContextMenu',cmenu);
hMain.Tabs.hPanel.setViewportView(hMain.Tabs.hTable);

% Set up CallBack
tableHandle=handle(hMain.Tabs.hTable,'callbackproperties');
set(tableHandle,'MousePressedCallback',{@mousePressedCallback,cmenu});

% Close Window
function CB_Project_Quit(hObj,eventData)
    delete(hObj);

% Turn on context menu at right mouse click (doesn't work!)
function mousePressedCallback(hObj, eventData, cmenu)
    if eventData.isMetaDown  % right-click is like a Meta-button
        clickX = eventData.getX;
        clickY = eventData.getY;
        myPosition = [clickX clickY];
        set(cmenu,'Position',myPosition,'Visible','on');
    end
```

Comment: The code is incomplete and impossible to run.

Comment: Noted.  Will post a more complete code profile tomorrow.

Comment: Code profile updated.  Thanks...